# J code writes csv (tables/csv: writecsv) losing significant digits (not always using engineering notation)

Tags: csv, j

```
   load 'tables/csv'
   a=. 2 4 $ 1.2345e_10
   makecsv a
1.2345e-10,1.2345e-10,1.2345e-10,1.2345e-10
1.2345e-10,1.2345e-10,1.2345e-10,1.2345e-10

   b=. 2 4 $ 1.2345e_8
   makecsv b
0.000000012,0.000000012,0.000000012,0.000000012
0.000000012,0.000000012,0.000000012,0.000000012
```

The csv package relies on J's internal format function: `8!:0`. According to [J dictionary](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx008.htm),

> exponential notation is used for non-zero numbers with magnitude less than 1e_9 or greater than 2e9

Otherwise, there can only be max of 9 digits after the decimal point.

```
 (8!:0) 1.2345e_10
+----------+
|1.2345e-10|
+----------+

(8!:0) 1.2345e_8
+-----------+
|0.000000012|
+-----------+
```

The question is how to keep the significant digits in the case of `1.2345e-8`?

Comment: If you want to use `tables/csv` you have to convert your numbers to strings first: `(0j_10&":)&.> b`. I don't see any way around this. Maybe the use of `8!:0` in `makedsv` is unfortunate.

Comment: @Eelvex thanks for the suggestion. `":` formats nicely, but the result is a csv file with strings (with double quotes), not numbers. I also tried to replace `8!:0` with your `":` in dsv packge directly. The problem is that now negative number `_1.23e_8` stays `_1.23e_8` rather than `-1.23e-8`.

Comment: after some trial and error, this is what i ended up doing. i went into addons/tables/dsv/dsv.ijs file and replaced `8!:0` with `(('%g' & sprintf) &. >)` and added `require 'format/printf'` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: (8!:0) ":!.9 [ 1.2345e_8


Format ": with fit !. and an argument of 9  might help?